# Error trying to run SkypeKitVideoDemo for Android

Tags: android, skype

When I try to run the SkypeKitVideoDemo for Android on my Galaxy Tab it crashes with the following error log in LogCat:

```
10-04 11:12:16.310: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3880): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-04 11:12:16.310: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3880): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
10-04 11:12:16.310: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3880):     at com.skype.ref.SkypeKitVideoDemo.       <init>(SkypeKitVideoDemo.java:92)
10-04 11:12:16.310: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3880):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
10-04 11:12:16.310: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3880):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1301)
10-04 11:12:16.310: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3880):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1022)
10-04 11:12:16.310: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3880):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1666)
10-04 11:12:16.310: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3880):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1767)
10-04 11:12:16.310: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3880):     at  android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:122)
10-04 11:12:16.310: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3880):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1005)
10-04 11:12:16.310: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3880):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-04 11:12:16.310: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3880):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
10-04 11:12:16.310: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3880):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4028)
10-04 11:12:16.310: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3880):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-04 11:12:16.310: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3880):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
10-04 11:12:16.310: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3880):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:844)
10-04 11:12:16.310: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3880):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
10-04 11:12:16.310: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3880):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-04 11:12:16.310: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3880): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load SkypeKitVideoDemo: findLibrary returned null
10-04 11:12:16.310: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3880):     at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:425)
10-04 11:12:16.310: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3880):     at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:554)
10-04 11:12:16.310: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3880):     at com.skype.ref.NativeCodeCaller.<clinit>(NativeCodeCaller.java:33)
10-04 11:12:16.310: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3880):     ... 16 more
```

Looks like an library problem, but I'm not sure how to set up the libraries. Has anyone been able to get the skypekit demo to run on a device? If so, how did you do it?

Answer (score 0):

FYI for anybody else having this issue: it seems like more than a library problem. Here's the response I got from the SkypeKit Forum:

Unfortunately the reference-android application is not in good shape in the current release.  You can expect fixes and improvement in future releases.

In 3.5, it is a useful starting point for experienced Android developers, showing the primary differences between Android and desktop Java clients: the SkypekitRunner class to initialize the application (which has atrophied and needs attention), the LocalSocketTransport socket implementation, the native code media hosts. But it will not work without significant modifications. Probably not a good place for a newbie to start.